# Every time I turn on macbook pro I get menu for choosing startup disk

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, startup

Every time when I turn on my macbook pro mid 2014 I have to choose my startup disk to continue with booting. It behaves as if I am holding the option key...

However, the right option key doesnt work when I want to use it in the OS.

When I turn on MP and hold the left option key it starts booting without boot menu, when I do not hold it it shows the menu. 
When I hold the right option key there is no difference.

I have tried apple diagnostics and it shows that everything is ok. 
Tried resetting SMC and PRAM and doesnt work.

Comment: Is this question about figuring if your keyboard is broken or NVRAM setting are broken? If you could edit in a specific question at the end of your post, we might be able to help you. If the keyboard is malfunctioning that would explain your situation quite clearly.

Comment: Usually the PRAM (now called NVRAM) does that, It contains the choice of start up disk. your selected startup disk, speaker volume, screen resolution, time zone... so to verify your reset to factory settings was successful do following. Change Volume to Zero, or change time zone, or change screen resolution. Now do the reset and look if the values are back to Factory settings.

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here due to lack of information, just trying to help.

Your Mac is 4 Years old, and probably (if you are like me) you have a "lunch" stuck under the right Option key.

Clean it.

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+To+Fix+Sticky+Keyboard+Keys+on+a+MacBook/37709

If that did not help you might have to replace the key.